# SQL using count and max functions at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query and it brings me how many people live in which country.
`Select Country, COUNT(EmployeeID) from Employees group by Country`

What kind of query should I use if I want to get the most populated city and the number of people living in it?

The code I tried :
`Select Country, MAX(COUNT(EmployeeID)) from Employees group by Country`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TOP` :

```
Select TOP 1 Country, COUNT(EmployeeID) as [count]
from Employees
group by Country
order by [count] desc
```

Comment: It is probably a good practice to avoid naming columns the same as service words...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. qty - count for country, maxqty - max count for all country.

```
Select Country
  ,COUNT(EmployeeID) qty
  ,MAX(COUNT(EmployeeID))over() maxqty
from Employees 
group by Country
```

For test data

```
create table Employees (EmployeeId int,country varchar(20));
insert into Employees values 
 (1,'country1'),(2,'country1')
,(3,'country2'),(4,'country2'),(5,'country2')
;
```

Result

| Country | qty | maxqty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| country1 | 2 | 3 |
| country2 | 3 | 3 |